# Why is appium throwing error when desired capability is using variable

Tags: android, node.js, appium

I am trying to write a test automation to log test result post completion & i need to log the device name and result post completion.

Everything seems to work expect when  i set the desired capabilities device name value as a variable it fails.

```
let desiredCaps = {
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '9',
        deviceName: Name,
        app: Apk,
        fullReset: false,
        automationName: "UiAutomator2"
    };
```

I  have tested by changing the value to a static value:

```
let desiredCaps = {
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '9',
        deviceName: 'testDevice1',
        app: Apk,
        fullReset: false,
        automationName: 'UiAutomator2'
    };
```

It works just fine without any issues.

```
const Set_Desired_Device_Capabilities = async function Set_Desired_Device_Capabilities(Port, Name, Apk) {
    let driver = await wd.promiseChainRemote({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: Port
    });
    let desiredCaps = {
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '9',
        deviceName: Name,
        app: Apk,
        fullReset: false,
        automationName: 'UiAutomator2'
    };

    console.log(desiredCaps);
    await driver.init(desiredCaps);
    await driver.setImplicitWaitTimeout(30000);

};


module.exports = Set_Desired_Device_Capabilities;
```

With the above code i end up getting this error:

```
init(
     {
       "platformName":"Android",
       "platformVersion":"9",
       "deviceName":"testDevice1",
       "app":"/Users/username/Downloads/test.apk",
       "fullReset":false,
       "automationName":"UiAutomator2"
     }
  )
] Parse Error
```

Is there a workaround for this or a better way to pass the device name as variable ?

Comment: There should not be any problem as long as the variable stores a string in it. Could you please paste the section where you are initializing this variable for device name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

The problem is with the asynchronous job I have in exported functions.